# Remove duplicate index in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have this 2D numpy array here:

```python
arr = np.array([[1,2],
                [2,2],
                [3,2],
                [4,2],
                [5,3]])
```

I would like to delete all duplicates corresponding to the previous index at index 1 and get an output like so:

```python
np.array([[1,2],
          [5,3]])
```

However, when I try my code it errors.
Here is my code:

```python
for x in range(0, len(arr)):
    if arr[x][1] == arr[x-1][1]:
        arr = np.delete(arr, x, 0)

>>> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to delete from the array, you can use [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to find the indices of first occurrences of the unique values in the second columns and use that to pull those values out:

```
import numpy as np   

arr = np.array([[1,2],
                [2,2],
                [3,2],
                [4,2],
                [5,3]])

u, i = np.unique(arr[:,1], return_index=True)

arr[i]    
# array([[1, 2],
#       [5, 3]])
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't follow the "*delete all duplicates corresponding to the **previous index***" rule, if there were another group of 1s after the 2s it would be deleted completely (which my be wanted, or not...)

Comment: That's a fair point @mozway, I certainly didn't read it that way, but on re-reading, it's a reasonable interpretation.